# unable to run docker container as getting this error:Unable to access jarfile app.jar

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I have created the image using below Docker file.Its working fine in local when I run it in the container using this image[docker run -p 80:8080 username/spring-boot-docker-aws-demo:tag

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
COPY target/spring-boot-docker-aws-demo.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

I have pushed this image to Docker hub to run it in EC2 instance.when I run it its saying "Error: Unable to access jarfile app.jar"

https://hub.docker.com/layers/chaituu/spring-boot-docker-aws-demo/docker-aws-demo-tag/images/sha256-110363a016eb2250264d96c8890dede518d8e519fdc9a27174334fe1096a540e?context=repo

what could be the issue?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue today (although in my case it wouldn't even run locally). Here's what your `Dockerfile` would look like with my fix:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
COPY target/spring-boot-docker-aws-demo.jar /app/app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["sh"]
CMD ["-c", "java -jar /app/app.jar"]
```

Comment: This isn't a great use of `ENTRYPOINT`: it can cause really confusing behavior if you try to `docker run --rm yourimage /some-script.sh` (works) vs. `docker run --rm yourimage ls /` (fails).  You also shouldn't need to write out `sh -c`, since just specifying `CMD java -jar /app/app.jar` automatically inserts it for you.  Other than the explicit `/app` path, this looks basically the same as the Dockerfile in the question.

Comment: @David Maze You've got a point that I could've just skipped the entrypoint and used `CMD java -jar /app/app.jar`. As for the explicit path, I've been thinking that the working directory specified in the image may be overwritten somehow (like if you run the image with `docker run --workdir /somedir ...`.

Comment: @Konrad Botor not working even after modifying the changes .strangely its working in local but once I pushed the image to DockerHub and running in EC2 box then seeing this error. sudo docker run -p 80:8080 chaituu/spring-boot-docker-aws-demo:docker-aws-demo-tag
Error: Unable to access jarfile app.jar

Comment: Are you sure your EC2 instance pulled the latest version of the image, rather than using the cached, old one?